# How do I turn this into a function?

Tags: function, powershell, timestamp

I found this script on this site <thanks Nick!>

```
   $files = gci $srcpath

foreach ($srcfile in $files) {
  # Build destination file path
  $dstfile = [string]($dstpath, '\', $srcfile.name -join '')

  # Copy the file
  cp $srcfile.FullName $dstfile.FullName -whatif

  # Make sure file was copied and exists before copying over properties/attributes
  if ($dstfile.Exists) {
   # $dstfile.CreationTime = $srcfile.CreationTime
   # $dstfile.LastAccessTime = $srcfile.LastAccessTime
    $dstfile.LastWriteTime = $srcfile.LastWriteTime
   # $dstfile.Attributes = $srcfile.Attributes
   # $dstfile.SetAccessControl($srcfile.GetAccessControl())
  }
}
```

I want to turn this into a function so it accepts recursive directories to copy the timestamps from the source, a cloud folder to it's equivalent at the destination.

Now, I have tried calling the function using multiple variables, trying different methods such as:

$src = $args[0]

$dst = $args[1]

Get-Timestamp $src, $dst

either uses the default folder that the script is running or will fail when it tries to list the contents combining the 2 variables together.

even setting up the function like so

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParamerterSetName='Srcpath')]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = 'Srcpath',
Position = 0)]
[string[]]$Srcpath,

```
   # [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, 
   # ParameterSetName = 'DSTpath',
   # Position = 1)]
    [string]$DSTpath
    )
    $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

is not producing the expected result.

This will work on its own, doing one folder at a time. But not when doing subfolders.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to build and use functions is a common thing and part of a day one PowerShell class/workshop/webinar/Youtube video. What you are doing is a very common thing s well, with tons of examples online, and direct examples in the PowerShell help files. There even snippets in the PowerShell ISE (CRTL+J to see/use them) as well as in VSCode (CRTL+ALT+J to see/use them). Computers and software are amazing things, but they are limited to what they are told to do. If you don't tell it something, it will not guess, well sometimes it tries to help, but not with your use case. Be explicit in code.

Answer (score 1):

From the PowerShell ISE or VSCode select a simple or advanced function snippet.
PowerShell ISE - use CRTL+J, type function, hit enter and you get this:

```
function MyFunction ($param1, $param2)
{

}
```

VSCode - use CRTL=ALT+J, type function, hit enter and you get this:

```
function FunctionName {
    param (
        OptionalParameters
    )
    
}
```

Put your code below the param block. Now, both those function names are not best practice and should be verb-noun, as documented here:

> [About Functions | MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=About%20Functions%201%20Short%20description.%20Describes%20how%20to,...%2010%20Function%20Scope.%20...%20More%20items...%20)
>
> ***Function Names***
>
> You can assign any name to a function, but functions
> that you share with others should follow the naming rules that have
> been established for all PowerShell commands.
>
> Functions names should consist of a verb-noun pair in which the verb
> identifies the action that the function performs and the noun
> identifies the item on which the cmdlet performs its action.
>
> Functions should use the standard verbs that have been approved for
> all PowerShell commands. These verbs help us to keep our command names
> simple, consistent, and easy for users to understand.
>
> For more information about the standard PowerShell verbs, see Approved
> Verbs in the Microsoft Docs.

You are not getting a recursive search because you are not telling it to. That is what the `-Recurse` of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet is for.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Path
LiteralPath
Filter
Include
Exclude
Recurse
Depth
Force
Name
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
UseTransaction
Attributes
Directory
File
Hidden
ReadOnly
System
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
# Results
<#

Example 3: Get child items in the current directory and subdirectories

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\*.txt -Recurse -Force

Directory: C:\Test\Logs\Adirectory

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/12/2019     16:16             20 Afile4.txt
-a-h--        2/12/2019     15:52             22 hiddenfile.txt
-a----        2/13/2019     13:26             20 LogFile4.txt

    Directory: C:\Test\Logs\Backup

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/12/2019     16:16             20 ATextFile.txt
-a----        2/12/2019     15:50             20 LogFile3.txt
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online
```

Lastly, aliases/shorthand names are for interactive throw-away code, not in production/shared scripts. As discussed here:

> • Best Practices for aliases
>
> ```
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/best-practice-for-using-aliases-in-powershell-scripts
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-aliases-best-practices
> ```
>
> Why worry about aliases in the first place? ... There are two things
> at work when it comes to a script. The first is that ***no alias is
> guaranteed to exist*** —even aliases that are created by Windows
> PowerShell. ...

... and if you create custom ones, you can step on one already configured on a host.

Lastly, PSScriptAnalyzer, VSCode, etc., make all known aliases as errors, until you make them their full name. Custom aliases, you need to expand yourself. Never assume folks know them or care to. PowerShell is verbose for a reason (good/bad/indifferent is all opinion), easy to read for the most inexperienced, self-documenting, and easier to maintain. Make sure to read the available PowerShell Best Practice references that are available and remember, you write code for those who will use it or follow you or maintain it.